# Two divs, one inside the other. Parent scrollable. Child fixed.

Tags: html, css

I have two divs I want to place one inside the other. The parent div has height 100% and is x-scrollable (the content will overflow to the right).
The child div has a repeatable background image set through css.
I want to place it at the bottom of the parent div (above the scrollbar), like a footer but when the scroll is moved this div should stay still.

How can this be done?

Right now I have

```
.parent{
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed; }

.child{
height:33px;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background-image:url(<image_path>);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:absolute;}


<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the child div moves when scrolling the parent div.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. If the parent div is set to 100% width, there will not be any scrolling. Are there other elements set to a wider with within the parent div?

Comment: @Scott, Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTtFa/) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the child div unless there's some other content there in addition to the background image. You could do it all in the parent div.

JSBin Demo -------> [HERE](http://jsbin.com/etomug/edit#html,live)

After your fiddle... an edit... Forget the background of the child div. Place the background image on the parent div. let the child div be transparent and contain the text.

Updated Fiddle --------> [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YTtFa/1/)